# Place an element after 3rd line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<style>
  .ad { margin: 15px; height: 30px; background-color: #7f7f7f; }
  .article { width: 300px; font-size: 24px; line-height: 30px; border: 1px solid; }
</style>
<div class="ad"></div>
<div class="article">
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd
</div>
```

I want to place an advertisement inside the article, but I want always to be between the 3rd and 4th line.
Is this possible using only CSS?
If not, is there any way to achieve this using Javascript or PHP?
I have the article in a string in PHP, but I don't know where is the 3rd line.

Please note that the article is in HTML format and may include HTML tags, so I cannot count characters.
Also, the .ad tag can be before or after the .article tag.

Thanks in advance for your valuable help!

Comment: You'd have to break the article yourself so that the advertisement is placed correctly.

Comment: Articles are imported automatically from 500+ RSS feeds and they don't have the same layout. Can you suggest me an automated way to place the ad after the 3rd line?

Comment: I guess, you could try to hack the data then.. for e.g., after you set the `.article`, get the text (not html) that is set in it and get the device width. then try and figure out the end of the 3rd line in the text and add a `div` to it. Then you can place the advertisement into the new `div` that you added.

Comment: @Sachin sounds interesting, but I don't know how to do it. Can you be so kind and write the code as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In html, You can't go to next line with `Enter key`, Line break tag is `<br>` in html.
So your code must be something like this:

```
<div class="article">
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
  asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd<br>
</div>
```

You can use jquery to find 3rd line and add your `ad` div:

```
$(".article br:nth-child(3)").after('<div class="ad"></div>');
```

Comment: I know this. But my question is different!
The article is in one row and it is wrapped automatically.